# Are you affected by dispel magic greater when you use the area dispel?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

When you use [dispel magic great](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dispel-magic) with area dispel option, are you and your belongings affected?

> Area Dispel: When greater dispel magic is used in this way, the spell affects everything within a 20-foot-radius burst. Roll one dispel check and apply that check to each creature in the area, as if targeted by dispel magic. For each object within the area that is the target of one or more spells, apply the dispel check as with creatures. Magic items are not affected by an area dispel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you target it on yourself, yes. It's much like dropping a fireball on yourself, in that regard.

From [Aiming a Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell):

> Most spells that affect an area function as a burst, an emanation, or a spread. In each case, you select the spell's **point of origin and measure its effect from that point**.
>
> **A burst spell affects whatever it catches in its area**, including creatures that you can't see.

Just target the centre of the burst somewhere else in range if being affected by it is undesired.

Comment: I needed to ask another question to make sure it was possible to cast it elsewhere, so I had first asked this question if that was not the case

Comment: @Fering It can sometimes make sense to wait a little bit between questions like these, since getting the first one answered might make the second unnecessary to ask.